# How can I query work items and their linked changesets in TFS?

Tags: hyperlink, tfs-workitem, changeset

In TFS 2010 I have **work items** with linked changesets.  I can generate a query that reports the **work items** I'm looking for.  Now I want to do a query of **Work Items and Direct Links** that includes all the **changesets** linked to these work items.  In the query editor I can't find any means to specify a changeset as the linked-to item.  Are **work-items** the only output possible from a query?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just attended the Webinar *Improving Developer and Tester Collaboration* where I posed my question.  Instructor Ken Arneson of alpi.com confirmed that links to changesets are not reportable through Query Editor in TFS Team Explorer.  To access links to changesets, other tools must be used to access the "Cube". I have more to learn.

Comment: eh gads that sucks, I'm looking to do something similar, I want to view work items associated with change sets in a particular date range.  I'll comment or answer if I find anything useful.

Answer (score 25):

An option is to use the TFS API like the following snippet.

```cs
var projectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://localhost:8080/tfs"),
    new UICredentialsProvider());
projectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
var workItemStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
var versionControlServer = projectCollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var artifactProvider = versionControlServer.ArtifactProvider;
var project = workItemStore.Projects["Test01.MSFAgile.v5"];
var teamQueryFolder = project.QueryHierarchy["Team Queries"] as QueryFolder;
var query = teamQueryFolder["My Tasks"];
var queryDefinition = workItemStore.GetQueryDefinition(query.Id);
var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"project", query.Project.Name}
};
var workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query(
    queryDefinition.QueryText,
    variables);
foreach (WorkItem workItem in workItemCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("WI: {0}, Title: {1}", workItem.Id, workItem.Title);
    foreach (var changeset in
        workItem.Links
            .OfType<ExternalLink>()
            .Select(link => artifactProvider
                .GetChangeset(new Uri(link.LinkedArtifactUri))))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "CS: {0}, Comment: {1}",
            changeset.ChangesetId,
            changeset.Comment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you do a Query and include external link count >0 this will actually give you all work items that have changesets associated with it.

Comment: Hey, that was simple enough! My requirement was just to audit requirements without changesets, so this does what I need it to!

Comment: Keep in mind that Test Results will also increment the External Link Count, so this may not be the best approach if you use TFS for test execution.