# How to Query for Changesets in TFS Web interface

Tags: tfs, changeset

In TFS web interface I can query for items with various link types:

[image]

However, Changesets, while they are a legitimate and distinct link type in TFS are not included in that list:

[image]

Using the web interface, how does one query for Work Items that either do, or do not include links of the type Changeset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. There is just not changeset LINKS field in default TFS Work Item Query Editor on web interface. Since if  you do a Query and include external link count >0 this will actually  give you all work items that have changesets associated with it.

Another way is using TFS API to achieve it. Suggest you use the way provided by Buck in this great blog: [Listing the work items associated with changesets for a path](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2012/02/01/listing-the-work-items-associated-with-changesets-for-a-path/)

*More ways please look at  this similar question: [How can I query work items and their linked changesets in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956570/how-can-i-query-work-items-and-their-linked-changesets-in-tfs)*

Comment: External Link Count.  Who woulda thunk it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the REST API to query out the work items which associated with changes.

1- Do a Query and include `External Link Count > 0` (This will give you
    the work item list with the external link which also including linked to the
    changesets.)

2- List the work item **IDs** and use below PowerShell script sample to
    filter the work items which associated to changesets. (You can also export the list to a .csv file)

```
$baseUrl = "http://server:8080/tfs/CollectionLC/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=75,76,77,78&"+"$"+"expand=relations&api-version=1.0"            
$workitems = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value|where({$_.relations.attributes.name -eq 'Fixed in Changeset'})

$WorkitemResults = @()

foreach($workitem in $workitems){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "workitemId" = $workitem.id
          "workitemTitle" = $workitem.fields.'System.Title'
          "State" = $workitem.fields.'System.State'
          "CreatedBy" = $workitem.fields.'System.CreatedBy'
          "Project" = $workitem.fields.'System.TeamProject'
          "AssignedTo" = $workitem.fields.'System.AssignedTo'
        } 

    $workitemResults += $customObject       
}

$workitemResults | Select `
                workitemId, 
                workitemTitle, 
                Project,
                State,
                CreatedBy,
                AssignedTo #|export-csv -Path C:\WorkitemsWithChangesets.csv -NoTypeInformation`
```